# Wordpress plugin not activated because it gives a fatal error for custom wp query

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to develop a recommender plugin. It does not run though and gives the following error message..

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

The code is:

```
add_filter('the_content','Recommender_function');


function Recommender_function(){
$id=get_the_id();
if(!is_singular('post')){
return $content;
}
$terms=get_the_terms($id,'category');
$categoriesarr=array();
foreach($terms as $term)
{
$categoriesarr[]=$term->cat_ID;
}

$loop=new WP_Query(
array('posts_per_page'=>4,'category__in'=>$categoriesarr));
if($loop->have_posts()){
$content.='<h2>I say, you should also try</h2>
<ul class ="Recommendation">';
while($loop-have_posts()){
$loop-the_post();
$content.='<li>
<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
}
$content.='</ul>';
WP_reset_Query();
return $content;
}
}
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: Proper indentation and formatting is huge help when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two lines in your original:

```
while($loop-have_posts()){
$loop-the_post();
```

You are calling a function in a class instantiated as `$loop`, not a function named `$loop-have_posts()` or `$loop-the_post()`. So those two lines should look like this:

```
while($loop->have_posts()){
$loop->the_post();
```

And another thing I noticed is you are concatenating the `$content` string via `.=` but at no point do you initialize the string.  So I added a `$content = '';` before your `if()` loop. Hopefully that will work.

Additionally, I will say this: You really need to get in the habit of formatting your code for readability. It might seem like a pain while you are in the midst of coding, but the reality is the harder your code is to read, the harder a time you will have debugging it. And it makes it harder for others to assist you in debugging it as well.

So that said, I reformatted your function below:

```
add_filter('the_content','Recommender_function');

function Recommender_function() {

  $id=get_the_id();

  if (!is_singular('post')) {
    return $content;
  }

  $terms = get_the_terms($id,'category');
  $categoriesarr = array();

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $categoriesarr[] = $term->cat_ID;
  }

  $loop = new WP_Query (array('posts_per_page'=>4,'category__in'=>$categoriesarr));

  $content = ''; 

  if ($loop->have_posts()) {

    $content .= '<h2>I say, you should also try</h2>'
              . '<ul class ="Recommendation">'
              ;

    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $content .= '<li>'
                  . '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'
                  . get_the_title()
                  . '</a>'
                  .'</li>'
                  ;
    }

    $content .= '</ul>';

    WP_reset_Query();

    return $content;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `-` in function names. Your while loop uses this format twice, im guessing you meant to do `$loop->have_posts()` and `$loop->the_post()`.

```
while ($loop-have_posts()) {
    $loop-the_post();
    $content .= '<li>'
              . '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'
              . get_the_title()
              . '</a>'
              .'</li>'
              ;
}
```

Comment: would suggest the same